# Considering the next sequence, find its limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, induction

My name is Agapita and I need help with this exercise.

> Considering the sequence: $a_1=1$ and  for $n\geq 1$,
>   $$a_{n+1}=\frac{n(a_n)^2}{n+1}$$
>   Find its limit.

The only thing that I could think of is that the limit of $a_{n+1}$ must be the same as $a_n$, but I don not know if this thought is correct neither how to continue it.

Thank you so much :)

If you don't understand the exercise, please let me know, I'll try to be clearer.

Comment: Pleas, learn to [use mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  to write mathematics.

Comment: Hint: by induction, $a_n \in [0,1]$ and $a_n$ is monotonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. If $a_n$ is a convergent to a finite limit $L\in\mathbb{R}$ then by taking the limit in both sides of the given recurrence we have that
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{n(a_n)^2}{n+1}\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot \left(\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n\right)^2\implies L=1\cdot L^2.$$
Show that for $n\geq 2$, $a_n\in (0,1)$ and that the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is decreasing.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why do multiply it by 1?

Comment: @Agapita See my revised answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much :)